# How to get Email messages in .msg format from Microsoft Exchange server using C#

Tags: exchange-server

I have a requirement that i need to pull the ".msg" files from one of the exchange server's public folder and save them in a network path.

I read a lot about Exchange Web Services Managed API, but I don't think there is a direct way to get ".msg' file. We can either retrieve ".eml" file or read subject, body, recipients  separately and generate ".msg" file. But both the options are not straight forward.

Can anyone suggest me a best way to achieve this using .net code using C#.

Thanks
Sreecharan

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the actual files but can you use the `Exchange Web API` to get the text of the message.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd637749(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have already tried using EWS API but i have to build a .msg file with the content. Is there any way to get the message file directly?